# pgfplots: change order of barplots

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

When one has more then one barplot in one pgfplots axis like in the following example then the red plot at the **top** of the code ends up as the **bottom** bar of the plot. I do find this confusing -- particularly as I have to make a legend in a list at the end and have to reverse the order there.

Is there any way to get the red bars to the top without changing the order in the code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar,]
\addplot[fill=red]
coordinates {(1,1)};
\label{red}

\addplot[fill=blue]
coordinates
{(1,1)}; \label{blue}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\ref{blue}] blub
\item[\ref{red}] red
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch the order by calling `xbar=-2pt, bar width=-10pt` (the negative of the default values for the gap between bars and the width of the bars):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar=-2pt, bar width=-10pt]
\addplot[fill=red]
coordinates {(1,1)};
\label{red}

\addplot[fill=blue]
coordinates
{(1,1)}; \label{blue}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\ref{blue}] blub
\item[\ref{red}] red
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you could use

```
xbar,
/pgf/bar shift={%
        % total width = n*w + (n-1)*skip
        % -> subtract half for centering
        0.5*(\numplotsofactualtype*\pgfplotbarwidth + (\numplotsofactualtype-1)*(2pt))  - 
        % the '0.5*w' is for centering
        (.5+\plotnumofactualtype)*\pgfplotbarwidth - \plotnumofactualtype*(2pt)}
```

which is the negative of the function used for offsetting the bars.

Comment: So "shift" was the keyword, bot reverse ;-). In my real case, I have various plots with varying numbers of plots. I also have a "bar distance" of 0pt, so I will use your second sugestions and replace the 2pt with 0pt.